# What does "the higher time" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, definition

A field-and-track man run 100 yards dash in 9.3 seconds, but the judge give him 9.4 seconds saying "We have to go with the higher time". What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is a number of seconds so, in this case, "the higher time" means "the bigger number of seconds".  "Go with" means "use" or "choose". So the judge is saying that, given the choice of using 9.3s or 9.4s as the athlete's time, they have to choose 9.4s.  (I'm not sure what the context is that means they have to do this.)

Comment: So, if the time was 9.34 seconds, a jugde would've chose 9.4 instead of 9.3, right?

Comment: @DmitriyEsarev I'm just explaining the language -- I've no idea what they'd actually choose or why.

Comment: They maybe have more than one person or machine timing the event. If one says 9.3 and another says 9.4, The judge would say "we had to go with the higher time".